# UPDATE записей если есть id в admin

Tags: php, sql

Нужно сделать `UPDATE` записей в таблице у которых в поле есть `id1|` при этом поле `admin`  выглядит так или так `idN|` или `idN|idN|....`

N - число любое

Comment: Лучше структуру базы переделать, что бы не было списковых полей. Ну если очень хочется то concat('|',поле,'|') like '%|id1|%' ну в конец '|' можно не добавлять к полю, если там точно она есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте LIKE:

```
UPDATE ...
WHERE admin like '%id1|%'
```